# Error while comparing two methods

Tags: java, casting, compareto

So I'm trying to do a simple program that can find the module of a Complex Number using generics and compares two modules:

```
public class ComplexNumber <T extends Number,U extends Number>
    implements Comparable<ComplexNumber<T, U>>
{
    private T real;
    private U imaginary;

    public ComplexNumber(T real, U imaginary)
    {
        this.real=real;
        this.imaginary=imaginary;
    }

    public T getReal()
    {
        return real;
    }

    public int compareTo(ComplexNumber<?, ?> o)
    {
        return this.modul().compareTo(o.modul());
    }

    public U getImaginary()
    {
        return imaginary;
    }

    public double modul()
    {
        double c=Math.sqrt(real.doubleValue()*real.doubleValue()+imaginary.doubleValue()*imaginary.doubleValue());
        return c;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%.2f+%.2fi", real.doubleValue(), imaginary.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

However it gives me two real time errors one in the .compareTo function stating:"Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double"

and one in the beginning of the class:     "Multiple markers at this line
        - The type ComplexNumber must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Comparable>.compareTo(ComplexNumber)
        - The type ComplexNumber must implement the inherited abstract method "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(ComplexNumber<T, U> o) {
        // logic
}
```

**edit**

if you definitely need to use wildcards then you'll need to change the class declaration to:

```
class ComplexNumber <T extends Number,U extends Number> implements Comparable<ComplexNumber<?, ?>>
```

in which case you can leave the `compareTo` method signature as is.

regarding the first error you've received, this is because you're trying to call the `compareTo` method on a primitive type `double` which would not work at all. To solve the problem, you'd want to use `Double.compare` and pass in the appropriate data.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(ComplexNumber<?, ?> o) {
       return Double.compare(modul(), o.modul());
}
```

Comment: Nope can't do that. It says that a wildcard must be used in the method.

Comment: who said that..?

Comment: In my assigment it says I need to use a wildcard.

Comment: @DavidMathers Then put your requirements in your question.